# Catch exception from async process in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Assume I'm sending an email, asynchronously, and want my program to continue its execution. So far, I've been doing this with `future`s, but unfortunately, when the email fails to send, no exception is raised.

I understand that dereferencing the future will raise an `ExecutionException`, but derefing would defeat the point.

Is there a better way to "fire and go", without losing exception information?

Comment: What do you want the exception to do? Since a future just does its thing and then it is done, an exception in the future should not stop the main execution thread. If you catch the exception inside the future itself you can have it log or try to recover in that context.

Comment: @noisesmith Sometimes you might want to stop the main execution Thread, if the job the future is doing is primordial to the correctness of the main Thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with agents for this, using handler functions to handle exceptions thrown by agent actions:

```
(agent initial-state :error-handler handler-fn)
```

See `(doc agent)`, `(doc set-error-handler!)`, `(doc set-error-mode!)` for details. `initial-state` here might simply be `nil`, or perhaps a structure holding some logging data.

To make this convenient, you'd want to have an `email` function usable with `send` (`send-off`, `send-via`):

```
(defn email [agent-state message] ...)
```

If the main thread needs to be notified that something is amiss, it will need to pay attention to communications over some channel. (Java queues are one possibility, the channels of [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async) are another.) The handler function can then push messages over that channel.

Comment: Quick question: What's the point of `initial-state`? Is that to report back to the main thread? If I don't want to report anything – I merely want to sleep well knowing my email didn't silently fail – do I need to set the agent's state?

Comment: Agents are one of Clojure's reference types; they always hold some internal state. If you only use an Agent for performing side effects asynchronously and have no use for any particular state value, you can set the state to `nil` and have the functions you pass to `send` (`email` in this case) return `nil` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Without trying...

```
(def foo (future (Thread/sleep 5000) 
                 (throw (Exception. "bananas!")) 
                 (Thread/sleep 5000)))

(future-done? foo)
;=> false
```

*5 seconds later...*

```
(future-done? foo)
;=> true

@foo
;=> Exception bananas!  user/fn...
```

With trying...

```
(def bar (future (try (Thread/sleep 5000) 
                      (throw (Exception. "bananas!")) 
                      (Thread/sleep 5000) 
                      (catch Exception e (println "Oh, " (.getMessage e))))))

(future-done? bar)
;=> false
```

*5 seconds later...*

```
;=>Oh, bananas!

@bar
;=> nil
```